# Markup extension naming

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I'm pretty sure the answer is **no**, but is there a way to name a markup extension differently from the class that implements it?

I would like to make a markup extension that has a relatively short name:

```
<TextBlock Text="{my:Ext}"/>
```

but I would like to give it a different (longer) name on C# side:

```
public class MySpecificMarkupExtension : MarkupExtension
```

The only information I found about naming is on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#StarExtension) and the `*Extension` pattern, which is not what I want to achieve. I was hoping an Attribute would exists that allow me to do this:

```
[SomeAttribute("Ext")]
public class MySpecificMarkupExtension : MarkupExtension
```

But I've checked most of the attributes in the [System.Windows.Markup namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and there is no such attribute unfortunately.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Why would you want to use a different name in xaml? Ext will be hard coded anyway even if such attribute would exist so whats the point? Just give the class the right name in first place. You could sort of hide the original class name by having an empty class that inherits from your custom extension. Like this: `class Ext : MySpecificMarkupExtension {}` However, there is no point in doing this..

Comment: Because I want to improve the readability of xaml with short names, but I have a large number of markup extensions to deal with, in a namespace with a large number of classes in which I would like to keep meaningful prefixes/suffixes for class names. It is definitively not pointless in my case.

Comment: You speak of large number of extensions. That is usually not the case or shouldn't be when you working in wpf. Extensions make only sense when you in a need to use IServiceProvider (I guess thats how is that service called). For everything else you should consider using Binding to a property in your ViewModel. Extensions like {LastName John} which return result is "John Smith" shouldn't be defined as extensions. I hope you get my point. However here is link to all attributes and extensions in xaml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Markup(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well no, there is no problem to have a lot of extensions. Xaml is very verbose and sometimes not very convenient, it is natural to extend it. The most common example is probably using markup extensions for value converters (It is actually one of the things I am currently doing with my extensions, but I have also other ones).

Comment: Well I posted you an answer how you could sum up your extension into one :) Extension for converter sometimes do no make sense since extension will always return a new instance of converter while when converter in resource its instance will be reused which is the proper way to solve this and keep clean memory footprints :) Therefore be careful how you define your extensions and what value they return.

Comment: I will comment your answer right after. You can use a static singleton to prevent re-instancing the converter multiple times. I use a solution similar to Sony's WPF framework, with a generic class containing a static (and generic) lazy-instanced singleton. https://github.com/SonyWWS/ATF/blob/master/Framework/Atf.Gui.Wpf/Markup/ConverterMarkupExtension.cs

Comment: There is no point in discussing this too much. Of course there are approaches to solve any technical issues. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is as you may have already assumed NOPE. There is no such class attribute. None that I know.

Since you mentioned you have a large amount of exceptions and you would like to keep xaml as simple as possible how about you have just one extension that calls others based on a key.

Its like hiding all those extension behind a certain key.

Take a look at this:

```
public class MyExtExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Output
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public MyExtExtension(string output)
    {
        this.Output = output;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this.Output;
    }
}

public class MarkupExtensionChooser : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public StringList Param
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (this.Key.Equals("ext"))
        {
            return new MyExtExtension(this.Param.Data[0]).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }

        if (this.Key.Equals("ext123"))
        {
            // Custom Logic
        }

        if (this.Key.Equals("ext123123123"))
        {
            // Custom Logic
        }

        if (this.Key.Equals("ext123123123"))
        {
            // Custom Logic
        }

        if (this.Key.Equals("ext12121412423"))
        {
            // Custom Logic
        }

        return this;
    }
}

public class StringListTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string val = (string)value;
            return new StringList(val.Split(','));
        }

        return null;
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(StringListTypeConverter))]
public class StringList
{
    public string[] Data
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public StringList(string[] data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

I ended up creating that "chooser class" which can also accept parameters and based on the key I return the necessary extension.

The TypeConverter is just there to allow having `Param="args1,args2,args3"` in xaml.

This is how my example in main window looks like:

```
<TextBox Text="{local:MarkupExtensionChooser Key=ext, Param='hello,world'}"/>
```

`Hello` will be displayed in TextBox since I pass param[0] to MyExtExtension.

It works fine for me but I am not sure if you can use something like this.

The idea is pretty simple however in the end its a bit of wpf tricking behind this and if you cannot follow let me know. I ll gladly assist you any futher.

Comment: This approach is interesting but it does not what I want, because many of my markup extensions have custom constructor parameters and/or properties to be set, and even if I can make a global markup extension that could fit them all, that would unlikely improve the readability (nor the verbosity) of my xaml files.

Comment: I guess you are stuck then with giving proper name to your classes.

Comment: yep :( I spend a little time watching the code of markup extensions with DotPeek and it seems there is no alternative for naming markup extensions. I'll accept your answer, since the "NOPE" seems definitively correct.